# Which Vagrant Ubuntu box to use in order to install latest Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I tried to use many different Vagrant Boxes which I found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/). I tried:

- hashicorp/precise64
- ubuntu/trusty32
- ubuntu/trusty64
- ubuntu/xenial64

but when I try to install latest Node.js (7.5) with (I found this on [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
```

I always get error like this:

**Your distribution, identified as "precise", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support**

I also tried to download ISO image for latest Ubuntu server and install it in VirtualBox manually and in that case installation of latest Node.js works fine. **Which Vagrant Box should I use?**

Additionally I use Mac OS with VirtualBox to run Vagrant.

My Vagrant config file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3309

end
```

Comment: ubuntu/trusty64 will work - I am using both trusty and xenial and they work. how is your Vagrantfile ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I updated question description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with version of Linux when I ssh to machine it's not enough to do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I must also do:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

After that installation of latest Node.js goes well.

**EDIT 5 January 2018**

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8000
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => ".provision/bootstrap.sh"
end
```

.provision/bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade

sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties
sudo apt-get update

# install packages
sudo apt-get -y install curl git

# nginx
sudo apt-get -y install nginx
sudo service nginx start

# remove default nginx config
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# set up nginx server
sudo cp /vagrant/.provision/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf
sudo chmod 644 /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf
sudo service nginx restart

# clean /var/www
sudo rm -Rf /var/www

# symlink /var/www => /vagrant
sudo ln -s /vagrant /var/www

# Node
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

nginx/nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name todo.dev;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root   /var/www/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that this was older version of node 6.x but you will probably only need to switch url in bootstrap.sh script to newer version. I don't use Vagrant anymore (instead I use Docker now) so I am not up to date with it.

Comment: which version of nodejs? and can you please add full vagrant file (or at least box name and provisioning script for node)

Comment: @epeleg I updated the answer. you will probably only need to change this line curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash - in boostrap.sh script to install latest node.js.

Answer (score 0):

well the following works for me and install nodejs

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3309

    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash - && apt-get -y install nodejs"

end
```

node gets installed as part of the initial provisioning

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ node --version
v7.5.0
```

Comment: I run with that but I still have old version of Node.js: v0.6.12

Comment: weird ... can you make sure to destroy the VM first! `vagrant destroy && vagrant up`

Comment: I tried that more than 10 times. I agree this is very strange. Some other suggestions?

Comment: I finally found solution for the problem but still thanks for help.